# Why template argument deduction fails?

Tags: c++

Minimized example:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct Deducer {
    Deducer(int) {}
};

template <typename T, int N = 1>
void foo(Deducer<T, N> d){}

int main() {
    foo<char>(345);
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/5-5rrf)

Yields error

```
candidate template ignored: could not match 'Deducer<char, N>' against 'int'
```

Why compiler ignores implicit cast?

If any simple workaround possible here?

I can think about two options:

(1) Specify all template parameters (not an option for me, real case have many of them, I want deduction)
(2) Write intermediate function like this:

```
template <typename T, int N = 1>
void foo_step(int d){ foo<T, N>(d); }
```

Not an option either, I have large number of arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: _Why compiler ignores implicit cast?_ because that's how it's specified in C++. No implicit cast in template type deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions):

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can try having something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U, int N = 1>
void foo(U&& u)
{
    foo(Deducer<T,N>(std::forward<U>(u)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the workaround I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

`N` is deducible in

```
template <typename T, int N = 1> void foo(Deducer<T, N> d)
```

So default value `= 1` is mostly useless.

If you want to force to call the method like:

```
foo<char>(345);
foo<char, 42>(345);
```

You might do:

```
// in C++20, std::type_identity might be used instead:
template <typename T> struct non_deducible { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using non_deducible_t = typename non_deducible<T>::type;

template <typename T, int N = 1> void foo(non_deducible_t<Deducer<T, N>> d);
```

But you no longer can do:

```
foo(Deducer<char, 42>());
```